# How to solve a segmentation fault when calling a subroutine within a subroutine in FORTRAN 77?

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, subroutine, fortran77

I'm struggling with a segmentation fault problem in FORTRAN 77 since a few months and I really can't figure out where I am wrong. I am a total newbie with Fortran.

I'm writing a program (`main`) in which I call a subroutine (`source`). This subroutine performs the 4th order Runge-Kutta method (as proposed in *[Numerical Recipes in Fortran 77](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/numerical-recipes/numerical-recipes-fortran-77-art-scientific-computing-volume-1-2nd-edition)* by Press, Teukolsky, Vetterling, Flannery) to solve a differential equation and advance certain input data values from a time instant to the next.

In order to perform the Runge-Kutta method, in `source` another subroutine `deriv` is called, which numerically computes the derivative in the differential equation. The subroutine `deriv` has to be called four times for the Runge-Kutta method, and I have to perform it for data values in both directions x and y: so, globally, `deriv` is called eight times within `source`.

The values to advance through Runge-Kutta are collected into vectors of maximum size `mxnn=200000` (a parameter included in `param.fi`), but in the course of the program only a part of them (of size `nodes`) will be filled and so advanced. These vectors are passed to `source` and their components are passed to `deriv` for the Runge-Kutta method.

This is the excerpt of `main` (it is a really big program so I've cut out what I deemed unnecessary):

```
      PROGRAM main

      INCLUDE 'param.fi'

      INTEGER nodes
      DOUBLEPRECISION z0
      DOUBLEPRECISION deltaxnp1(mxnn),zxnp1(mxnn),u0xnp1(mxnn)
      DOUBLEPRECISION deltaynp1(mxnn),zynp1(mxnn),u0ynp1(mxnn)
      DOUBLEPRECISION deltaxn(mxnn),zxn(mxnn),u0xn(mxnn)
      DOUBLEPRECISION deltayn(mxnn),zyn(mxnn),u0yn(mxnn)

      ...
      ...

      CALL source(nodes,                                  
     +        z0,deltaxn,u0xnp1,u0xn,zxn,zxnp1,deltaxnp1,
     +        deltayn,u0ynp1,u0yn,zyn,zynp1,deltaynp1,
     +        [...])

      ...
      ...

      END program main
```

This is the subroutine `source`, which I've written in a different module:

```
      SUBROUTINE source(nodes,
     +     z0,deltaxin,u0xnew,u0xin,zx,zxout,deltaxout,
     +     deltayin,u0ynew,u0yin,zy,zyout,deltayout,
     +     [...])

      INTEGER nodes, i
      DOUBLEPRECISION z0
      DOUBLEPRECISION deltaxin(*),u0xnew(*),u0xin(*)
      DOUBLEPRECISION zx(*), zxout(*),deltaxout(*)
      DOUBLEPRECISION deltayin(*),u0ynew(*)
      DOUBLEPRECISION u0yin(*),zy(*),zyout(*),deltayout(*)
      DOUBLEPRECISION duxdt(mxnn),duydt(mxnn)

*** Variables needed for Runge-Kutta ***
      DOUBLEPRECISION dtmezzo,d6,th
      DOUBLEPRECISION dzini(mxnn),dzt(mxnn),dzm(mxnn)
      DOUBLEPRECISION zt(mxnn)

      DO i=1,nodes

      ...

         dtmezzo=dt*0.5D0      
         d6=dt/6.D0                                        
         th = time + dtmezzo

*** Runge-Kutta for values in x direction
*** INPUT: zx(i)         
*** OUTPUT: zxout(i)

         CALL deriv(zx(i),u0xnew(i),z0,duxdt(i),dzini(i))
         zt(i)=zx(i)+dtmezzo*dzini(i)

         CALL deriv(zt(i),u0xnew(i),z0,duxdt(i),dzt(i))            
         zt(i)=zx(i)+dtmezzo*dzt(i)

         CALL deriv(zt(i),u0xnew(i),z0,duxdt(i),dzm(i))
         zt(i)=zx(i)+dt*dzm(i)
         dzm(i)=dzt(i)+dzm(i)

         CALL deriv(zt(i),u0xnew(i),z0,duxdt(i),dzt(i))
         zxout(i)=zx(i)+t6*(dzini(i)+dzt(i)+2.*dzm(i))

*** Runge-Kutta for values in y direction
*** INPUT: zy(i)         
*** OUTPUT: zyout(i)

         CALL deriv(zy(i),u0ynew(i),z0,duydt(i),dzini(i))   !!!!!
         zt(i)=zy(i)+dtmezzo*dzyini(i)

         CALL deriv(zt(i),u0ynew(i),z0,duydt(i),dzt(i))            
         zt(i)=zy(i)+dtmezzo*dzyt(i)

         CALL deriv(zt(i),u0ynew(i),z0,duydt(i),dzm(i))
         zt(i)=zy(i)+dt*dzm(i)
         dzm(i)=dzt(i)+dzm(i)

         CALL deriv(zt(i),u0ynew(i),z0,duydt(i),dzt(i))
         zyout(i)=zy(i)+t6*(dzini(i)+dzt(i)+2.*dzm(i))

         ...

      ENDDO

      RETURN
      END
```

And here is the subroutine `deriv`:

```
      SUBROUTINE deriv(Z,u0,z0,dudt,der)

      DOUBLEPRECISION Z,u0,z0,dudt,der

      der = ( (((0.4D0**2)*u0)/z0) - Z*(dexp(Z)-Z-1) 
     +         * (dudt/u0) ) / ( dexp(Z)*(Z-1)+1 )

      END
```

While compiling the program (with GNUfortran) it gives me no problem: but after running the program a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error appears and the program aborts. After a bit of analysis it seems that the problem lies when I call `deriv` for the first time for the values in the y direction (i.e. the fifth call, which I labeled with `!!!!!` in the code).

It's strange to me, since if I try to compile and run the program *without* the y direction block (solving Runge-Kutta only for the x direction) everything goes fine. The form of `deriv` is exactly the same for both directions: only the inputs and outputs change.

I checked the array dimensions and nothing seems wrong (to me at least), and I fear that there is a conceptual error in my script. I went through various answers here at Stack Overflow but to no avail.

I considered debugging with `dbg` and the `-g` flag, but the program is made through a makefile and I couldn't find how to use the flag with it.

Comment: You say "which I've written in a different module".  If this is truly F77 then there is no such thing as a module.  You just mean that it's in a separate file?  [Even with what is clearly fixed-form source it could still be a version of Fortran supporting modules.]

Comment: how is `nodes` related to `mxnn`? perhaps you are trying to save the result of `deriv` into an invalid element of `dzini`...

Comment: You need to figure out how to add bounds checking to your compilation process.

Comment: @francescalus: thank you for your inputs. Yes, it is fixed-form

Comment: @francescalus: thank you for your inputs. Yes, it is fixed-form code: I will format the code correctly from now on. I misused the term "module" indeed: the code for `source` and `deriv` are written in separate files. I'm still searching for how to add debug flags in my makefile... do you happen to know some references I could turn to?

Comment: @ewcz: `mxnn` is a parameter from `param.fi` and is set to 200000. `nodes` is a number which is always lower than `mxnn`, and represents the number of nodes of an user-made mesh which is analyzed at the beginning of `main`. A separate subroutine analyzes the mesh, counts the number of nodes and stores its number into `nodes`.

Comment: @ewcz: as for your second suggestion, I did not verify it. `dzini` (as well as `dzt` and `dzm`) is used for both Runge-Kutta applications: it's used for the x direction first and then re-used for the y direction. It would sound odd to me that `dzini` is populated correctly for x and incorrectly for y, since the processes are the same. I will check it out anyway. Thank you.

Comment: @Ross: thank you for your input. Do you mean with the `-fcheck=bounds`? I still don't know where and how to use it in the makefile.

Comment: Yes, you should prioritize figuring out how to adjust the build process to include compiler-time flags to help you debug. `fcheck=bounds` (or whatever equivalent your compiler uses) and the like are critical aspects of debugging.

Comment: @Ross: I'm reading about makefiles on the GNU online manual right now. I hope it will help me figuring my error out.

Comment: The makefile will probably have something like FC=...gfortran... and FCFLAGS.  Add -g and -fcheck=bounds to FCFLAGS,